# How to remove OneToMany relationship from two entities?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I've got the same OneToMany relationship in two diffrent classes X and Y, and when I'm trying to remove it there's an exception: `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find with id... <entity>`

I've got also a XY class with two ManyToOne relationship, which has embedded id consisting of id from X and id from Y class.

I've tried something like removing relationhip from list in X and Y class, merging it and then delete the relationship from XY class. I've tried adding annotation @NotFound with NotFoundAction.IGNORE and it works, but I can't use it. Also I think it isn't resolving my problem, It's something like workaround.

```
//from X class:
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "x", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<XY> xy;

//from Y class:
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "y", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<XY> xy;

//from XY class:
    @EmbeddedId
    private XYid xyid = new XYid();

    @MapsId("xId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "x")
    private X x;

    @MapsId("yId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "y")
    private Y y;

//from XYid class:
    private Integer xId;
    private Integer yId;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of removing the OneToMany annotation ? You need to add the annotation if there exists a ManyToOne relation in most scenarios. Refer for details  - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html

Comment: I didn't want to remove OneToMany annotation, or maybe I don't understand your response.

Comment: The first line of the question says you encountered an exception when you tried to remove the relationship. Can you re-phrase ?